# How to get the count of total likes from all posts which are posted by one user in android firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The structure in which I store the likes of a post is as shown below :

[image: show in this image]

This is how I store the information of a post:

[image: post information]

UID is of the user ID of the user who posted the post of course.

I want to get the **total number of likes** that a particular user with **UID** **got on all of his posts**

For example:

A user with uid: Avvj7v9v has two posts with 4 and 2 likes, respectively.
So, the total number of likes that all of his posts got is 6.

I want a way to get that number of likes which is 6 in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `databaseReference.child("Posts")` and loop through all the posts, find those whose `uid` child matches the desired user, and keep that subset of post IDs, say in an ArrayList, `postsOfTheUser`.

Next, go to `databaseReference.child("Likes")` and loop through all the likes. Ignore all children whose post ID is not in `postsOfTheUser`, but those whose post ID is in `postsOfTheUser`, proceed to sum the likes, using `getChildrenCount()` for each of the posts.

Comment: I was actually thinking the same but didn't know on how to go on actually implementing it

Comment: @Atharva_I It would be better for your learning if you try to implement according to this approach, and then if it doesn't work, you can post the code above. Then people can help to point out what could be changed/fixed. Can you update your post with your code for this?

Comment: @Atharva_I How was it? After you implemented it, was it working?

Comment: No, I was able to get the number of likes of first post only not all the posts. (and because of time being I implemented that only in my project)

Comment: Ok, if you've time in the future and try to complete the implementation and have any issues, let us know and we can take a look.

Comment: Yeah sure, I will try it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
databaseReference.child("Likes").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        long size = snapshot.child(UUID).getChildrenCount();
        sum += size;
        textView.setText("Total Likes for this User: " + sum);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

Comment: what ```holder.getTextViewPostThreadsCount()``` actually does ?

Comment: @Atharva_I example like this.

Comment: I think what you have return will give me count of how many posts a certain user liked ? @Ticherhaz

Comment: No, I want to get the count of likes of all posts which are posted by a user with certain uid  @Ticherhaz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212145/discussion-between-atharva-i-and-ticherhaz).